# Cannot set placeholder attribute using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, placeholder, document-ready, dom-manipulation

I'm having trouble setting a placeholder on an input field. Here's the DOM:

```
<td id="searchSoNo" class="searchField">    
<input class="normal" type="text" size="30" name="opValueDet0" value="">
</td>
```

The following function runs on page load.

```
$('#searchSoNo > input').attr('placeholder', 'SO no');
```

The function runs fine and I can set other attributes like 'id' and 'rel' using the following code in place of the above.

```
$('#searchSoNo > input').attr('id', 'soNo1');
$('#searchSoNo > input').attr('rel', 'relText');
```

But, the placeholder doesn't seem to be working at all. Any pointers?

Comment: Seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/j6Lxm3hs/. Check the console for errors and ensure you have only one `#searchSoNo` element in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
    <td id="searchSoNo" class="searchField">    
    <input id="myInput" class="normal" type="text" size="30" name="opValueDet0" value="">
    </td>

<script>

$('#myInput').attr("placeholder","MyPlaceHolder");
//or
$('#myInput').prop("placeholder","MyPlaceHolder");

</script>
```

> or

```
        <td id="searchSoNo" class="searchField">    
        <input class="normal" type="text" size="30" name="opValueDet0" value="">
        </td>

    <script>

$('#searchSoNo > input[type="text"]').prop("placeholder","MyPlaceHolder");

</script>
```

Comment: This is identical to what the OP already said bar the selector, so I'm not sure what difference you're expecting it to make.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand also way but if you set an ID on the input and get element by ID it will work.

```
<td id="searchSoNo" class="searchField">    
<input id="ipt" class="normal" type="text" size="30" name="opValueDet0" value="">
</td>

$('#ipt').attr('placeholder', 'SO no');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a4d44xo2/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. I see that it's working elsewhere (in your jsfiddle for example). But doesn't seem to work on my page unfortunately. I tried debugging and can see that the placeholder is set, but is removed afterwards.

As a solution, I have moved the script to the window.load (from document.ready) handler and it's working fine now.

Thank you again for all the input.